# Spanish for "to no end"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, gramática

Consider the following translation:

> **His laziness disgusts me.**
>
> *Me da asco su flojedad.*

What if I wanted to add "to no end" to the sentence?

> **His laziness disgusts me to no end.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

> Su flojera me da un asco infinito.

Comment: Flojera? Isn't it flojedad? What's the difference?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia according to the dictionary, they are synonyms. I've never heard *flojedad* used, but it could be a regional issue. You can also use *pereza*.

Comment: Also, any reason for the "un" there? Would "me da asco" be less appropriate than "me da un asco"?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia the "un" is necessary when you add "infinito". "me da un asco" by itself would be incorrect.

Comment: One last question: Which country are you from? I ask this so as to understand any inherent regionalism in your translation.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia I'm from Argentina, but there we would never use "flojera" or "flojedad", we could say "vagancia" or "dejadez". But regarding your original question, if you google "asco infinito", you'll find that it is also used in Spain and other countries.

Comment: Coincido con @rsanchez : 'lazyness' no es "flojera" sino "vagancia" o "dejadez".

Answer (score 2):

There isn't exactly a perfect translation for this because it is an expression, a very colloquial one at that.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69501/meaning-and-usage-of-to-no-end

You're best choices for communicating the same expression would be:

`Su flojera me disgusta ...`

- Interminablemente
- Incesantemente
- hasta la saciedad
- hasta el hastío
- hasta la madre
- hasta siempre
- sin parar

Comment: I totally understand that and that's why I am keen on knowing how this expression is used in different Latin cultures. Which country are you from? And how is this expressed in your dialect of Spanish?

Comment: Spanish is not my native language, and as you can see from my profile, I am from North Carolina; making English my native language.